# Going directly to result page in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-search, documents

Consider following scenario:
You use windows search to find XYZ inside PDF,DOCX or DjVu files of a folder. Windows return some result. You open first file of result and again use adobe reader find to locate the exact place the XYZ.

Is there a way that when you open a result file, reader app show result page?

Comment: Have you tried something on Google?

Comment: AFAIK there is no way yet to do this. Just press ctrl+F in afobe reader to search the word.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that when you open a result file, PDF reader app show result page?

Not that I know of.

But you **can** search inside several PDF files using Acrobat Reader directly. When you click on a search result, it will lead you directly to the location where it was found.

To start a search, go to `Edit -> Search` or press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: @Reza That's because Adobe Reader multi search does not using any index, unlike Windows 7 built-in search, which does.
For me the possible solution would be a custom app for searching where it use Windows/or it's own index.